# Theme setting, fonts, and graphics quality changing without prompt

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I'm writing a script which is based in a dropbox folder, working between a mac and a PC. One day, with nothing changed, the graphics no longer reads the Windows fonts database, and the plots themes are no longer being applied. I can manually set the font using

```
windowsFonts(Lato =windowsFont("Lato"))
```

but it doesn't fix the thematic settings, nor change the font where specified (annotations).

This script is not reproducible, but shows what thematic settings I have:

```
data  %>%
      ggplot((aes(x = year, y = sum, group = country_classification, color = country_classification)) +
      geom_line(aes(color = country_classification), lwd = 1.5, alpha=.7) +
      scale_color_gcf(palette = "mixed")+
      theme_bw(base_family = "Lato") +
      xlab("") +
      ylab("")+
      scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = 4, xend = 4, y = 7836967, yend = 2440845), 
                   lty = 2, lwd = .5, colour = "darkgray") +
      annotate("text",x = 3.7, y = 5000000, family = "Lato",
               label = "$5.3M \nDifference \n2018") +
      geom_point(aes(color = country_classification, size = sum), alpha = .7) +
      labs(title = "Annual Disbursement Sums by \nCountry Classification")+
        theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
        theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
        theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
        theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())  +
        theme(panel.border = element_blank()) + 
        theme(axis.line = element_blank()) +
        #theme(panel.grid = element_blank())+
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10))
```

brings this warning message:

```
In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database
```

`dev.off()` results in "Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)"

But this is giving the output desired either. `Image 1` shows my initial output, `image 2` shows the output now, using the same code. Can notice the quality difference in lines, and thematic settings changed (font, line quality)

**Image 1:**

[image: image1]

**Image 2:**

[image: image2]

Comment: recently updated R/ ggplot2/ windows/ OSX ?

Comment: I know - might not be exactly satisfactory - but maybe use more commonly used fonts instead, especially when you want to distribute your script ?

Comment: @Tjebo I've updated R, I think the OSX and windows computers were on different versions...broke my script somehow...once fixed will comment if it worked. thanks for the comment.

Comment: Updating R + packages didn't provide a solution

Comment: just a wild guess, when you say that setting the font with windowsFonts(...) works - have you tried theme(base_family= windowsFonts(...)) ? (I actually usually use very common fonts so never run into problems like that

Comment: Also doesn't change. the font is one thing, but the entire graphic output is lower quality (e.g. look at the lines in image 2), which makes me think its a higher-level theme  / graphics issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It required a few extra steps,

First, adding the fonts using

```
extrafont::load_fonts(device = "win")
```

Second, by saving the output as a separate file (I was copying from clipboard initially) using ggsave, which let me specify the output quality.

```
ggsave("file.jpg", dpi = 500)
```